# google drive api v2 php

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

It does not work download files. The function of the documentation `https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads`

Writes: `Class 'Google_Http_Request' not found`,

here `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md` 
It is written that `Removed Google_Http_Request`.

If you use the likeness , changing it into a GET request and substitute a link , as described in the last link above

```
$httpClient = $client->authorize(); 
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', $url); 
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
```

Writes:

```
Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must implement interface GuzzleHttp\Message\RequestInterface, instance of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request given, called in \file.php on line 37 and defined in \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php on line 158
```

Those who have experienced this ? Any solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem with the Google Cloud Storage php API.   Try it like this:

```
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$response = $httpClient->get($url);
```

And then if you need to dump it out to the browser (like if you're retrieving an image):

```
echo $response->getBody();
```